# Web APIs in Desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

I have a desktop application built using .NET Framework 4.7.2. Now I have a requirement to build a rest API layer with it using which the functionality of the desktop application can be tested with other test tools I have.

So I need to start a web API on demand. Is there any way to start and stop a web API on-demand in .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Comment: Please add more details in your question. Do you need to test your _desktop_ application or you have to implement interaction with desktop application using web API? If you have to test your desktop application, then just cover your functionalities with tests. If your desktop application needs to interact with some kind of web API, then you have to write tests in web API or even make debug environment to test your features in desktop app.

Comment: The API layer is required to test the desktop application. Why I need an API layer to test the functionality is, I have a test tool that will interact with desktop application and test its functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key word to look for in this context is "self-hosting". This means that your process hosts a HTTP server that can be accessed from clients - e.g. a test tool as in your case.

This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) shows a sample that uses ASP.NET 4.x.

In order to only start the server when needed, you could add a configuration setting.

Comment: Many thanks. This showed the path for the solution

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear this.